# Can I write in an Input Register? Modbus

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I've been working for 2 months in a `MODBUS` project and now I found a problem.

My client is asking me to write in an input register (Address 30001 to 40000).

I thought that was not a thing for me because every `modbus` documentation says that 30001 to  40000 registers are read-only.

[image]

Is it even possible to write in those registers? Thanks in advance

Comment: Who is developing the slave device, you or your client? Or is it a pre-existing device?

Comment: @Tagli nice question :) The slave device is configured by the client. They gave me an .xml with the modbus map, and in several variables they are asking me to perform R/W in 3xxxx to 4xxxxx variables, which is not possible... What I'm developing is the comunication between that slave and my java application, which has to read variables and write on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both holding and input register related functions contain a 2-byte address value. This means that you can have 65536 input registers and 65536 holding registers in a device at the same time.

If your client is developing the firmware of the slave, they can place holding registers into the 3xxxx - 4xxxx area. They don't need to follow the memory layout of the original Modicon devices.

If one can afford diverging from the Modbus standard, it's even possible to increase the number of registers. In one of my projects, I was considering to use `Preset Single Register (06)` function as a bank select command. Of course, you can't call it Modbus anymore. But, the master can still access the slave using a standard library or diagnostics tools.

Comment: Your answer helped me to find what I was doing wrong. As you said, there are 65536 input registers. The restriction of being between 3xxxx and 4xxxx is just a convention... they can do whatever they want. So I'm able to write in 30120 using function fx03. Thanks!

Comment: If you say that a 3xxxx address is a Holding Register I and many others would say that you are wrong.This has a cleaner solution. Schneider, the current owner of Modicon, and other manufacturers too,  to exceed the 9999 register limit now use 6-digit addresses like 4xxxxx instead of 4xxxx, so there is no need to skip Modbus addressing rules. In the last Modbus driver I wrote I also used 6-digit addresses

Comment: I agree with you Lluis. But this is my very first project using Modbus and I didn't develop the slave... I was given a set of addresses I have to read/write and If they don't want to follow the Modicon protocol is not in my hand... And belive me it sucks because it took me more time to realize what they were asking for. Modicon protocol should be followed by everyone

Answer (score 3):

- You can't write to Input Contacts or Input Registers, there is no Modbus function to write to them, they are read only by definition
- Modbus is a protocol and in no case specifies where the values are stored, only how they are transmitted
- Currently there are devices that support 6-digit addresses and therefore can address up to 65536 registers per group

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... I think they just messed up with the modbus map asking me to do something impossible. Thanks Lluis, I'll accept answer tomorrow unless someone tells me a hacky way to do it :)