# How can I write in Modbus input register?

Tags: modbus

I am working at Modbus client(master) application, and I want to write some data in the input register. I have no idea to implement it. I would appreciate somebody could tell me.
There are some posts like [Can I write in an Input Register? Modbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885379/can-i-write-in-an-input-register-modbus), but I did not understand that.

Comment: What is the device in question (please provide its manual)? By definition, you can't write into an input register, they are read only. The answer to the linked question mentions this too.

Comment: @tagli I am building the server at MITSUBISHI PLC and the client on the Windows platform.